# How to use equipment in outdoor "fitness stations"?

Tags: gym, exercise-technique, exercise-equipment

Councils in my city have started installing what I think of as adult playgrounds, things called "fitness stations" or "outdoor exercise equipment" apparently that have unusually shaped static objects and machines.  For example, http://www.woollahra.nsw.gov.au/recreation/fitness_training/exercise_equipment_in_parks  Some of this equipment is quite traditional and in wood, which I remember from childhood as the "really boring playground."  Other equipment is ornate mechanical machines.

Strangely I've found it difficult to find people suggesting fun & safe ways to use this equipment.  The manufacturers and installing councils don't seem to suggest ways to use the equipment online.

The more complex machines seem to make sense as their form implies natural kinds of use (rowing, skiing, cycling) that are limited in their movement.

The simpler machines, like an oblique twist seat, don't imply their function because they seem useable in so many ways to me.

The static objects seem even stranger to me, as an angle bar about waist/knee height could be used in any number of ways.  So could three upright poles at ankle-knee height.  I assume each object has an implied function or set of functions that's beyond me.

The only source I could find for suggested methods of using these devices was one authority's video'd sessions (  , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZBRw-_fyyk ), but these aren't named by device and aren't exhaustive.

Sometimes installed equipment have panels explaining their use, but these rapidly degrade to unreadable due to graffiti, sun exposure or rain exposure.

I assume that there are "go to" works in print for enjoying these objects, because there don't seem to be compilations online.

I have no health or fitness goals, I'm just interested in safely playing on the new equipment I keep seeing while cycling.

Comment: Can you be specific (MSPaint/Photo?) about the equipment you cannot work out how to use? Generally, equipment is just that, you can use it however you want as long as it is in a safe manner. A pull-up bar could be used for a huge range of exercises.

Comment: For general ideas of what to do, look for bodyweight fitness books and guides, particularly ones with names like "playground workout" or "playground fitness". For more specific stations, you may be best off snapping a photo and asking here. If you do so, I'd recommend both posting the photo and a description so that it's helpful to later querents.

Comment: Thanks @JJosaur, I will try to take some photos while I'm out of the variety of equipment.  As I'm new to this exchange, would you recommend compiling them into this question, or making new questions, one per equipment type?

Comment: Put them in to your original question. This can be a catch-all for weird outdoor equipment types.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a lot of core exercises on these.

Examples: Pullups/chinups on the high bar. On the two low parallel bars, you can do different variants of dips. Usually, there'll be a very low bar to lock on your feet - so you can do situps. And the ground layer is soft and nice(but firm), making it really good for pushups(rather than on concrete).

Nothing too fancy, no. But a good amount of core bodyweight drills can be conducted with that setup :-)